# How can I check whether my phone is network locked (Samsung GALAXY S3)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sim-unlocking

I have a Samsung GALAXY S3 with a rooted Android 4.1.2. My network provider is AT&T.

I tried dialing `*#7465625#` but it doesn't work:

[image]
[image]

Comment: At the end of most unlock procedures is a way to verify that the procedure worked. So find a procedure that matches to your phone, OS, baseband, etc., and see if they tell you at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an app to do this, Samsung have removed/changed some of the Dialer codes on the Galaxy range.

[GalaxSim Unlock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spocky.galaxsimunlock&hl=en) seems to do what you want, it checks if SIM locked, and offers an in-app purchase to SIM unlock. Please note I have not tested this app.

You could also pop in a SIM from a friend's device that is on another network and that should tell you pretty quick!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it does look good but ironically it's not compatible with my device "This app is incompatible with all of your devices." :/

Comment: That... Makes no sense!! D'oh! Let me look for alternative methods!

Comment: It is also not compatible with my Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900A :/

Answer (score 1):

You can check easier just asking a friend to lend you their sim from another carrier for a minute, insert it and if it is locked the phone will ask you for a code.

Answer (score 0):

To use this [method](http://www.wikihow.com/Unlock-Samsung-Galaxy-Siii-(S3)) you need to update your S3 to 4.1.1 Jelly Bean which was released on December 3, 2013 by Samsung:

1. dial the following keys *#197328640#
2. Main Menu > [1](http://www.wikihow.com/Unlock-Samsung-Galaxy-Siii-(S3)) UMTS > [1](http://www.wikihow.com/Unlock-Samsung-Galaxy-Siii-(S3)) Debug Screen > [8] Phone Control > [6] Network Lock > Options [3]Perso SHA256 OFF
3. After choosing this option, wait about 30 seconds, then go back one step by pressing the Menu button then select Back, now you are in [6] Network Lock then choose [4] NW Lock NV Data INITIALLIZ: wait for a minute then reboot your phone.

(I personally don't have the [4] NW Lock NV Data INITIALLIZ, but I guess it might help others)